# Google Script Drive.Files.remove(idToDELETE) insuficient permission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a folder in which I want to delete a document permanently, so I call it by `Drive.Files.remove(idToDLET);`

I hava enabled the Drive Api and it's ok. I yet get the following error:

> insufficient permission for this file

What I am missing?

[image] and enabled in the console also here[image]

Edit : I took a look for the scopes and I have this [image] for the files I want to trash I am the owner and I don't know how to set the scopes in the manifest file so I don't think I do this

```
function supprime_all_Google_Docs_files_in_the_folder() {

  /** on va chercher dans le FOLDER_ID les Google Docs qui sont pareil ( c'est <<<< getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS) ) **/
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_ID).getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
  var file,idToDLET ;

  while (files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    idToDLET = file.getId();
    if( idToDLET != TEMPLATE_DOC_ID)
      Drive.Files.remove(idToDLET);  
    Logger.log('File id  ' + idToDLET);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't have the necessary OAuth scope. File -> Properties -> Scopes

Comment: Or the user you are acting as does not have permission to trash that file

Comment: Are you setting the scopes in the manifest file?

Comment: If you want to add the scope of ``https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"``, for example, you can achieve it by putting this comment ``// DriveApp.getFiles()`` in your script. Because the script editor can automatically detect a part of scopes from the script. In your script, your script editor might have already detected it.

Comment: So I am the owner of the folder and it's shared with my team i've edited the post and I don't think that i set the scopes in the manifest file(i don't know how to do it and what is the purpose because this is just a simple script and I am blocked for this )

Comment: Just because the folder is yours does not mean you get to trash files in it that others own. For those you do not own, you must `DriveApp#Folder#removeFile` instead of trashing. You can add a check in your code to print metadata for a file if you do not have permission to trash it - this will help you understand the error better.

Comment: I see because it's my own folder but it is inside a folder that I'm not the owner so I will impossible to trash it.I will try as you said thanks.